# Preloader spinner GIF not displaying on first render

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, backbone.js, ejs

I'm working on a Rails application with a Backbone front end. While waiting for an AJAX request to resolve, I have the Backbone router serve up a loading screen with a spinner GIF (47 KB). There are jQuery fade effects on the GIF's DOM element as well. Everything works fine, but if it's the first time the load screen is displayed in a while, the GIF never appears. It will then appear anytime the same page is accessed thereafter. Could this be due to the load time required for displaying GIF? If this were the case, would it appear once loaded or could jQuery interfere with that? From reviewing my code carefully I cannot see where the first load would encounter any alternative logic.

The HTML in a JST.EJS template:

```
<h1 class="loading-message"><%= message %></h1>
<img class="spinner" src="../spinner-light.gif" onload="$(this).fadeIn();">
```

The `render` function in the pertinent Backbone view:

```
  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template({message: this.message}));
    this.$el.find(".spinner").hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.$el.find(".spinner").fadeIn(1000);
    }.bind(this), 200);
    return this;
  }
```

The method in the Backbone router, inserting the rendered "loading" template, and replacing it upon a successful AJAX request:

```
quizShow: function (regionId) {
  this._swapView(new Chickadee.Views.Loading({message: "Loading quiz..."}));
  if (this._requireLoggedIn()) {
    var quiz = new Chickadee.Models.Quiz();
    quiz.save({region_id: regionId}, {
      success: function () {
        this._swapView(new Chickadee.Views.QuizShow({model: quiz}));
      }.bind(this)
      error: function () {
        this._swapView(new Chickadee.Views.NoQuiz());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  } else {
    this._swapView(new Chickadee.Views.Welcome());
  }
}
```

The _swapView function simply calls render on the new view's associated template and then inserts it into the body of the page.

Comment: Your onload may not work yet because JQuery has not been loaded.

I do not know backbone, but your render function could be failing for some other reason, such as your template not being loaded.

I suggest putting an alert in the timeout, and checking the console for any errors, then report back here.

Comment: I put an alert in the timeout's callback and it indeed fires when the spinner does not load, so the timeout is definitely being called. No errors either!

Comment: Please put codes where Your models/Collection or Controller whichever you use ajax connection to the server too.usually loading mask is called at where you call ajax call(basically Backbone's model/collection's fetch/sync).and removed when it finishes loading(success callback of ajax)
If the ejs file is the one which will be returned from server side,it doesn't make any sense because when you get the spinner html,You've already finished downloading data via ajax and showing spinner lasting 200ms AFTER ajax connection's finished.

Comment: The view with the loading spinner is inserted onto the page from the client side, before a model is then created and saved with an AJAX POST request. The loading page is then removed by that AJAX request's success callback. So, the spinner should be displaying so long as the AJAX request takes longer than the times I've specified, which it does not. I will add more code context to my question.

Comment: At this point, I suggest you create the simplest case possible in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/thomas/C9wew/6/), get the spinner working, and move up from there.